# JQuery to check for duplicate ids in a DOM

Tags: jquery, dom

I'm writing applications with ASP.NET MVC. In contrast to traditional ASP.NET you're a lot more responsible for creating all the ids in your generated page. ASP.NET would give you nasty, but unique ids.

I'd like to add a quick little jQuery script to check my document for duplicate ids. They may be ids for DIVS, images, checkboxes, buttons etc.

```
<div id="pnlMain"> My main panel </div>
<div id="pnlMain"> Oops we accidentally used the same ID </div>
```

I'm looking for a set and forget type utility that'll just warn me when I do something careless.

Yes i'd be using this only during testing, and alternatives (such as firebug plugins) are welcome too.

Answer (score 226, accepted):

The following will log a warning to the console:

```
// Warning Duplicate IDs
$('[id]').each(function(){
  var ids = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this)
    console.warn('Multiple IDs #'+this.id);
});
```

Comment: perfect! thanks! already discovered three places where I have duplicate IDs. it frustrates me slightly that most peoples solution to this problem is to use 'firebug' or 'html validator'. thats not good enough! i want to catch the unexpected duplicates in wierd situations.

Comment: hehe and i switched console.warn to alert(...) so i HAVE to fix them :)

Comment: have found this extremely useful and valuable. i think it ought to be a standard in frameworks - especially during debugging

Comment: The amount of DOM traversals required for this to work is pretty astonishing

Comment: Very nice solution but it needs extra quotes in `var ids = $('[id=\''+this.id+'\']');` so it works with dots and other weird things in IDs.

Comment: very useful code. saved me a whole lot of trouble and it can be pasted in to the console area for immediate gratification :)

Comment: How do I star a answer instead of question in this page? I want this answer to be saved.

Comment: Can anybody explain how to make it work for custom attributes, for example `theid` instead of `id` ?

Comment: @john , try this    jQuery('[theid]').each(function() { var theid=jQuery(this).attr("theid"); var ids = jQuery('[theid="'+theid+'"]'); if(ids.length>1 && ids[0]==this) {console.warn('Multiple IDs : '+jQuery(this).attr("theid"));}});

Answer (score 36):

This version is somewhat faster, and you can copy it to a bookmark button to make it a bookmarklet.

```
javascript:(function () {
  var ids = {};
  var found = false;
  $('[id]').each(function() {
    if (this.id && ids[this.id]) {
      found = true;
      console.warn('Duplicate ID #'+this.id);
    }
    ids[this.id] = 1;
  });
  if (!found) console.log('No duplicate IDs found');
})();
```

Comment: This algorithm is better, requires only one dom traversal instead of one per matched element. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It gives false positive for forms which have input with name=id.

`javascript:(function () {
  var ids = {};
  var found = false;
  $('[id]').each(function() {
    var id = this.getAttribute('id');
    if (id && ids[id]) {
      found = true;
      console.warn('Duplicate ID #'+id);
    }
    ids[id] = 1;
  });
  if (!found) console.log('No duplicate IDs found');
})();`

would be better.

Answer (score 14):

I have a big page, so that script runs too slow to finish (multiple "continue script" messages).  This works fine.

```
(function () {
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("*"), i, len, ids = {}, id;
    for (i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        id = elms[i].id || null;
        if (id) {
            ids[id] =  ids.hasOwnProperty(id) ? ids[id] +=1 : 0;
        }
    }
    for (id in ids) {
        if (ids.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            if (ids[id]) {
                console.warn("Multiple IDs #" + id);
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

Comment: great! thanks. i often forget I have this running in production and really ought to optimize it by now - or add a debug setting to turn it on/off!

Comment: I'm constantly working on combining scripts in different configurations and this will certainly help me a lot. Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for the plain JavaScript solution. After finding the duplicated ids, I used the a XPath expression (`$x("//*[@id='duplicated-id']")`) in the console to query the elements with the duplicated ids.

Answer (score 12):

You should try [HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249) (Firefox extension). It'll definitely tell you the page has duplicate ids and much more.

Answer (score 8):

Why don't you just validate your html?

Double ID's are not allowed, and normally you will get a parse-error.

Comment: what options are there for this?

Comment: Also in FF, use the web developer toolbar under tools it has validators

Comment: When working with widgets like dialog from jquery ui it happens often that you end up with dupliates in the DOM when not cleaning up after creating the dialogs.

Answer (score 7):

The top jQuery answer, rewritten in ES6:

```
  [...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].forEach(el => {
    const dups = document.querySelectorAll(`[id="${el.id}"]`);

    if (dups[1] === el) {
      console.error(`Duplicate IDs #${el.id}`, ...dups);
    }
  });
```

Comment: thank you! the days of jQuery are past (or should be)

Comment: Of course it'll take approximately 10 years for this 5-upvoted answer to move to the top near the 220-upvoted accepted answer, and my attempt to create a new question that would make this information more accessible was shut down as a duplicate, but that's StackOverflow for you

Comment: Seeing this again a year later, there's a more elegant way to check for dups and only log once using a single comparison, `if (dups[1] === el)`

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way of locating duplicates but this will add a class of error so it will have red text:

```
// waits for document load then highlights any duplicate element id's
$(function(){ highlight_duplicates();});

function highlight_duplicates() {
  // add errors when duplicate element id's exist
  $('[id]').each(function(){ // iterate all id's on the page
    var elements_with_specified_id = $('[id='+this.id+']');
    if(elements_with_specified_id.length>1){
      elements_with_specified_id.addClass('error');
    }
  });


  // update flash area when warning or errors are present
  var number_of_errors = $('.error').length;
  if(number_of_errors > 0)
    $('#notice').append('<p class="error">The '+number_of_errors+
      ' items below in Red have identical ids.  Please remove one of the items from its associated report!</p>');
}
```

Comment: thats kinda cool! thanks. i've actually found the original accepted answer invaluable. caught so many things and saved probably hours of time!

Comment: Cool, but why not just use console functions and let them do the rest? Separation of logic and presentation etc etc...

Answer (score 2):

This might do the trick
It will alert all the ids of elements with duplicates.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function findDupes()
       {
         var all = $("*");
         for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
         {
             if (all[i].id.length > 0 && $("[id='" + all[i].id + "']").length > 1) alert(all[i].id);
         }
       }
      </script>
     </head>
     <body onload="findDupes()">
      <div id="s"></div>
      <div id="f"></div>
      <div id="g"></div>
      <div id="h"></div>
      <div id="d"></div>
      <div id="j"></div>
      <div id="k"></div>
      <div id="l"></div>
      <div id="d"></div>
      <div id="e"></div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this because it spits out the actual elements to the console. It makes it easier to investigate what's going on.

```
function CheckForDuplicateIds() {
var ids = {};
var duplicates = [];

$("[id]").each(function() {
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
    if (ids[thisId] == null) {
        ids[thisId] = true;
    } else {
        if (ids[thisId] == true) {
            duplicates.push(thisId);
            ids[thisId] = false;
        }
    }
});
if (duplicates.length > 0) {
    console.log("=======================================================");
    console.log("The following " + duplicates.length + " ids are used by multiple DOM elements:");
    console.log("=======================================================");
    $(duplicates).each(function() {
        console.warn("Elements with an id of " + this + ":");
        $("[id='" + this + "']").each(function() {
            console.log(this);
        });
        console.log("");
    });
} else {
    console.log("No duplicate ids were found.");
}
return "Duplicate ID check complete.";
```

}

Comment: This function was extremely helpful where the suggested Chrome extension HTML validator did not work for me, because it was able to detect replicated ids when new HTML was added to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution which will print out in console a list of duplicate ids if any is present.

You can run the code directly in console (copy/paste) after you DOM is loaded and does not require additional dependence like jQuery.

You could use it to quickly found out possible errors in your HTML markup.

```
    (function (document) {
        var elms = document.body.querySelectorAll('*[id]'),
            ids = [];
        for (var i = 0, len = elms.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (ids.indexOf(elms[i].id) === -1) {
                ids.push(elms[i].id);
            } else {
                console.log('Multiple IDs #' + elms[i].id);
            }
        }
    })(document);
```

An example:

https://jsbin.com/cigusegube/edit?html,console,output

(here code is added before closing the `body` tag)

Answer (score 1):

We can directly paste the below script into browser console to get duplicate IDs

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].filter(el => [...document.querySelectorAll('[id]')].map(el => el.id).filter(id => id === el.id).length > 1);
```

Reference: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/getting-duplicate-ids-in-an-html-document

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function where you can inspect a specifically element searching for duplicated ids within or the entire page:

```
function duplicatedIDs(container) {

    var $container  = container ? $(container) : $('body'),
        elements = {},
        duplicatedIDs = 0;
        totalIDs = 0;

    $container.find('[ID]').each(function(){
        var element = this;

        if(elements[element.id]){
            elements[element.id].push(element);
        } else  {
            elements[element.id] = [element];
        }
        totalIDs += 1;

    });

    for( var k in elements ){
        if(elements[k].length > 1){
            console.warn('######################################')
            console.warn('        ' + k )
            console.warn('######################################')
            console.log(elements[k]);
            console.log('---------------------------------------');
            duplicatedIDs += elements[k].length
        }
    }
    console.info('totalIDs', totalIDs);
    console.error('duplicatedIDs', duplicatedIDs);
}

duplicatedIDs('#element'); //find duplicated ids under that element
duplicatedIDs(); // entire page
```