# Check for duplicate IDs in HTML code

Tags: c#, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I have a string that contains this HTML markup:

```cs
string markup = @"
  <html>
    <head>
      ...
    </head>
    <body>
      <input id='text1' />
      <input id='blah' />
      <input id='text1' />
    </body>
  </html>
";
```

How can I check for duplicate ID names?

Comment: you must read [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

Comment: You shouldn't use regex for this

Comment: I get voted down for a problem that I need help with? I'm not trying to parse the entire markup. I am just looking for a pattern of id="sameid" that's it. Still not possible? I did read the link above.

Comment: @Rod I think some people reflexively downvote whenever they see 'HTML' and 'regex' in the same sentence.

Comment: This question is in no way a duplicate of that other question (which exists more for comedic purpose than anything else at this point anyway). It is a legitimate question, as anybody who actually read it can see (rather than just voting to close because it mentions HTML and regex). At least link to a question that will be useful to the OP: [HTMLAgilityPack, HTML duplicate IDs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2693350/803925)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(markup);

var dups = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Where(n => n.Attributes["id"] != null)
    .GroupBy(n => n.Attributes["id"].Value)
    .Select(g => new { ID = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .Where(r=>r.Count>1)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression might work, but only if the HTML is **very** regular.  If you can't be sure of the number, types, formatting, and order of the attributes on those `input` tags, for example, then a regex-based solution to retrieving the information you want is going to be unwieldy at best, perhaps unworkable.

Better to use [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).  It will parse the HTML for you and spit out a tree representing the document structure.  Then you can just traverse it looking for `input` tags and grab their `id`s if they have them:

```
HtmlDocument doc;
var inputTags = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("input");
var ids = inputTags.Select(x=>x.Attributes["id"]);
```