# django bootstrap modal template for inline fields

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have "Post" and "Slide" classes in models.py:

```
class Slide(models.model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="slides")
name = models.TextField()
```

"Slide is inlined in "Post" in admin.py, I am using bootstrap for frontend. I want to display all "slides" for only that post when I click on a button but when it goes to modal it's only taking first post.id in modal, my template looks something like this:`

```
    {% if posts %}
        {% for post in posts %}
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sample-1"> Slides </button>

             <div id="sample-1" class="modal fade">
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    {% for slide in slides %}

                    {{slide.body}}

                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sample-1').modalSteps();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the same `id` for all items ... "sample-1"

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really

[JQuery to check for duplicate ids in a DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/482763/jquery-to-check-for-duplicate-ids-in-a-dom)