# Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined when I click submit button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I don't know why **I received this error when I changed the code to php (from html). when the extension of the file is html, the code is working fine**.

```
<?php?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/manual.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
 
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <title>Register</title>
</head>
 
<body>
 
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="navBar">
               
        </nav>
 
        <div class="full">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <!--Side Bar-->
                        <div class="col-xs-3" id="navSide">
                        </div>
 
                        <div class="col-xs-6" id="signUpForm">
 
                                <h1>Register Page</h1>
                                <form role="form" id="signUpForm">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <div class="form-inline spacer-12">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="userFirstname" placeholder="First Name">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="userLastName" placeholder="Last Name">
 
                                                </div> 
                                        </div>
 
                                        <div class="form-group ">      
                                       
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                                name="userEmail"
                                                placeholder="Email">
                                        </div>
 
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="userPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
 
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
 
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                                  <label> Birthday* </label>
                                                  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="userBirthday" placeholder="Birthday">
 
                                        </div>
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info spacer-12" style="clear:both" >
 
 
                                </form>
                               
 
 
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
 
 
        <script src="js/startup.js"></script>
        <script src="js/signup.js"></script>
 
</body>
</html>
 
<?php?>
```

then this is my jquery validation code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#signUpForm').validate({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "help-block",
        rules:{
            userFirstName:{
                required: true
            },
            userLastName:{
                required: true
            },  
            userEmail:{
                required: true
            },
            userPassword:{
                required: true
            },
            confirmPassword:{
                required: true
            },
            userBirthday:{
                required: true
            }
       },
       submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
           alert('valid form submitted'); // for demo
           return false; // for demo
       },
       highlight: function(element) {

        $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-error').addClass('red-border');
       },
       unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success').removeClass('red-border');
       }
   });
});
```

This code causes error when I click the submit button (JQuery Validate Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'settings' of undefined )
But the error is temporary and will vanish in a while.

Comment: What changes between clicking the button with an error, and clicking it without? Such errors won't simply "vanish". Additionally, what have you tried to spot differences when changing from HTML to PHP (whatever that means)? Is the markup still the same, like **exactly** the same?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You defined two ids with same name, whereas id should be unique.

```
<div class="col-xs-6" id="signUpForm">
<form role="form" id="signUpForm">
```

Try to remove id from `<div class="col-xs-6" id="signUpForm">`

Comment: what a stupid mistake, how do u check if there are 2 ids in the same form?

Comment: using `id` selector like so `console.log($('[id="signUpForm"]').length);`

Comment: okay thanks norli..i will accept ur answer soon, it is still hard if we need to check all the ids one by one haha

Comment: Yeah, avoid to define same id, instead use class for that. And you're welcome mate.

Comment: See this answer to find all duplicate ids https://stackoverflow.com/a/509965/989451

Comment: Theres actually a plugin in chrome for this called Dup-ID

Answer (score 25):

If you use the rules() method, make sure to initialize the validation first.

```
var validator = $("#Form1").validate();
$('#field1').rules("add", {
         min: 1
});
```

Comment: The above reply is specifically for the jQuery validator plugin.
It also perfectly answered my query, so thank you Michael

Comment: The initialization of jquery validate my form was wrong and your answer was essential to understand my problem.

Comment: This solved the issue I had "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')." Spent a while trying to figure this one out. Kudos.

Comment: I forgot you have to "slap" jQuery from time to time :D

Comment: I have multiple forms, and $('form').validate() does not initialize all forms properly. I must call them all individually: $('form').each((index, element) => { $(element).validate(); });

Answer (score 6):

This error is normally caused by trying to validate an element that is not a form. In the OP's case, there are two elements with the same ID:

```
<div class="col-xs-6" id="signUpForm">
<form role="form" id="signUpForm">
```

jQuery searches a page from top to bottom, and the first element it finds with this ID is not a form.

The [Validator.element()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.element/) function (for validating single elements) can also cause this error, if attempting to validate an element that is outside the form.

Comment: This seems like more of a comment than an answer to the question

Comment: This was the solution for me.I tried to validate a form that not exists.

Solve it adding a id on form to validate.

`$("#form_id").validate({...})`

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE two things**

**1. Define the Jquery function**

include the function of jQuery !

```
(function( $ ) {
```

*//Start Script*

*//endscript/*

```
})( jQuery );
```

2. **Change the Form Id because it's doing conflict between Form Id and Div Id**

`<form role="form" id="signUpForm1"> // include 1 in previous  form id`

***And put this id into script***

```
  $('#signUpForm1').validate({ // put the Id in the script
```

Hope Your Task will be successful.

Answer (score 2):

To add a small detail here, I ran into the same problem with jQuery UI time picker, and it also was due to the id being non-unique.

In my case, it's because I was grabbing the parent element from a template - duplicating it for a pop-up window.  As a result, the contents of the window all had duplicate ids.

My normal workaround for that was to replace this:

```
$('#foo').bar();
```

with this:

```
myPopupWindow.find('#foo').bar();
```

That works quite well for most things, but not for the time picker.  For that one, I wound up doing this:

```
myPopupWindow.find('#foo').attr('id', 'foo_' + someUniqueTag);
myPopupWindow.find('#foo_' + someUniqueTag).timepicker();
```

where someUniqueTag is a record id, random number or some other distinct string.  This solved it quite nicely for me.