# chosen dropdown cannot be identified using ID in javascript function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

I am using a couple of jquery chosen dropdowns in a nested gridview. When I call the .change event, the only way I can identify the chosen dropdowns is to use `$("select")`.  The problem is that I have one dropdown that is not a chosen type and the initial value of this dropdown is set to the empty string and I don't want that has an option for this dropdown.  So, when it displays, it is shown as very narrow.
This is the function call:

```
 $(function () {
         bindEvents();
     });

    //This change function is when the Device grid is in Insert Mode
    function bindEvents() {
        $(document).on("change", "#recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert", function () {
            $("select").prop("disabled", false);
            $("select:not(.chosen-select, .no-chosen)").chosen({
                search_contains: true,
                width: "200px",
                no_results_text: "Sorry, no match!"
            });

            var DeviceSelValue = $(this).val();
//This is the problem...
//I need to set the dropdown to the empty string
//this function call does not work
    //     $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").val('');
//This function call does work but sets all of the dropdowns to empty.
           $("select").val('');         
    //       $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").children("option").hide();
            $("select").children("option").hide();
            $("select").trigger("chosen:updated");
            //$("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").trigger("chosen:updated");

            switch (DeviceSelValue) {
                case "1":     
             //       $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert option[value*='cell']").show();
            //       $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("select option[value*='cell']").show();
                    $("select").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").hide();
                    break;
                case "2":
        //          $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert option[value*='email']").show();
        //          $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("select option[value*='email']").show();
                    $("select").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").hide();
                    break;
                case "3":                    
        //          $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert option[value*='page']").show();
        //          $("#recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("select option[value*='page']").show();
                    $("select").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $("#recdevgvAddressExtInsert").hide();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
     };
```

This is the markup of the nested gridview:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePnlDeviceNestedGrid" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <div id="div<%# Eval("RecipientID") %>" style="display:none">
        <asp:GridView ID="RecipientDeviceGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="grid" ShowFooter="true" Caption="Device Information" 
            CaptionAlign="Top" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="3" HorizontalAlign="Left"
             onpageindexchanging="RecipientDeviceGridView_PageIndexChanging" 
             OnPageIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_PageIndexChanged" 
             onrowcommand="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowCommand" 
             onrowediting="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowEditing"
             onrowupdating="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowUpdating"
             OnRowCancelingEdit="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowCancelingEdit"
             OnRowDeleting="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowDeleting"
             OnRowDataBound="RecipientDeviceGridView_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DeviceID">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Device"  ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblDeviceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceID") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditDeviceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("DeviceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                            data-placeholder="Choose device…" class="chosen-single">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameEdit" runat="server"  
                                ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate> 
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"
                            data-placeholder="Choose device..." class="chosen-single">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLDeviceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListDeviceNameInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                            ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service Provider">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblServiceName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditServiceName" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_EditServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true"
                             data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameEdit" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceName" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="RecipientDeviceGridView_SelectedIndexChanged_InsertServiceName" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
                            data-placeholder="Choose service…" class="chosen-single">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueDDLServiceNameInsert" runat="server" InitialValue="0" 
                                ControlToValidate="recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                                ErrorMessage="Selection required." CssClass="message-error-dropdown">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvEditAddressExt" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceExtension") %>' 
                                ClientIDMode="Static">
                        </asp:Label>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressEdit" runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation" 
                                ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressEdit" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddress" CssClass="message-error" 
                            ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressEdit" EnableClientScript="true" 
                            ValidationGroup="recdevEditDeviceValidation">
                        </asp:CustomValidator>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvAddressExtInsert" runat="server" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="recdevReqValueAddressInsert" runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation" 
                            ErrorMessage="Required field." CssClass="message-error">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="recdevCustomValAddressInsert" runat="server" ControlToValidate="recdevgvTxtBoxAddressInsert" CssClass="message-error" 
                            ErrorMessage="*" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateAddressInsert" EnableClientScript="true" 
                            ValidationGroup="recdevInsertDeviceValidation">
                        </asp:CustomValidator>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActive" runat="server" class="no-chosen"
                            Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("Active").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="recdevgvDDListActiveInsert" runat="server" class="no-chosen">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cortext Enabled">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="recdevgvLblCortextEnabled" runat="server" Text='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("CortextEnabled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False" ItemStyle-Wrap="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="recdevgvEditButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Edit" 
        Text="Edit" CssClass="gridActionbutton" ValidationGroup="EditDeviceValidation"></asp:Button>
```

Can anyone explain to me why the chosen dropdown will not recognize the ID?  I use a similar function call when I am in edit mode.

THanks

**UPDATE**
using the suggestion from 'ourmandave', to ID duplicate controls, I removed the attribute `ClientModeID = Static` and am trying to identify the control by this means:

```
var serviceNameCtrl = document.getElementById('<%= recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert.ClientID %>');
```

However, I must to doing it incorrectly because I keep getting the error 'The name 'recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert' does not exist in the current context'.  Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: Why not use `$(this)` instead of `$("select")`?

Comment: In Chrome console, you could try the command: `console.dir(document.getElementById("recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert"));` and see if Chrome can find the id.

Comment: Or check for [duplicate id's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/482763/3585500)?

Comment: I tried using `this` and it did not work.  Will look for duplicate IDS and the Chrome suggestion...thanks!

Comment: I added the duplicate id javascript function as suggested.  It is identifying duplicate ids.  This is a nested grid. I have the attribute for the controls set to `ClientIDMode = Static`.  Removing this eliminates the ID as a duplicate.  However, how to identify the control?  Do I have to use the entire name or is there an easier way?

Comment: Here's [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227176/3585500) with all the options you could try. The recommended one is trying unique classes with the cssClass (option 3).

Comment: I tried them all and none seem to work.  I had to define 2 of the 3 dropdowns using the class=chosen-single'.  so that is not unique.

Comment: Does calling the `bindEvents' function have to happen in an anonymous function?  If I could pass in an argument that IDs the grid that is expanded, that might help.

Comment: @GloriaSantin Yeah, extra class names won't work if the original control is being repeated because they'll just duplicate too. Here's an [MSDN page on Control ID's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx). You could try the ClientIDMode = 'Predictible' and see what HTML is generated as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381611.aspx).

Comment: Setting the control `recdevgvDDListServiceNameInsert` attribute ClientIDMode = Predictable actually worked!  Thanks for hanging in there with me.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: Be sure to create an answer that I can endorse!

Comment: @GloriaSantin I'm just glad it worked! I don't know when they added predictible, but there's a lot of old posts and blogs where the answer had the caveat that it wouldn't work with repeating controls.

Comment: From my preliminary testing, it seems to do the trick.